does localhost refer to user/client or the machine the web app is running
Im using net core api as my backend
I have a method that loopback or callback to itself (localhost), after process is finish
will this work when running on a server?
will that localhost refer to the client/user or the machine where the web app is running

localhost refers to where that method executes.

localhost will always be evaluated on the system, where it is called. When using it in the C#-Code on the server app, it will reffer to the "host" where the app is executed. This may also be the docker container, where the app is running (so you would not reach e.g. a database in a different container on the same host using localhost).
If you call localhost in the browser of the client using javascript, this will be resolve to the client and the client will call itself (e.g. used by some apps to communicate with a website).
localhost will be resolved either to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 or [::1]. But for IPv4 any address beginning with "127." is a loopback address, pointing to the own host.
In case you want to avoid using the hostname of the server in your code, at least in browsers all paths that start with / (e.g. /api/users will be evaluated for the currently visited website).
